# t sql call function as while parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

is it possible in T SQL to use a function as a while parameter? I have the following code:

```
    create function LoginExists (@p_login char(6))
returns varchar(5)
begin
    if exists(select * from Student where student.slogin = @p_login)
        return 'true'
        return 'false'
end;
```

and

```
    create procedure AddStudent2
(@p_fname varchar(30), @p_lname varchar(50), @p_tallness int)
as
declare @p_login char(6), @p_email varchar(50), @suffix char(3);
set @p_lname = LOWER(@p_lname);
set @suffix = '000';
begin
    set @p_login = substring(@p_lname,1, 3) + @suffix;
    while (LoginExists @p_login = 'true')
        set @suffix = cast((CAST(@suffix as int) + 1) as char(3));
            set @p_login = substring(@p_lname,1, 3) + @suffix;
    set @p_email = @p_login + '@vsb.cz';
    insert into Student values (@p_login, @p_fname, @p_lname, @p_email, @p_tallness);
end;
```

and when trying to compile it, an error occurs, saying: "Incorrect syntax near '@p_login'."

Comment: Function calls need to be qualified with a schema name, e.g. `while ( dbo.LoginExists( @p_login ) = 'true' )`.

Comment: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."... but thanks anyway.

Comment: I'll guess that the new error occurs on the `insert into Student` statement.  What is the schema for `Student`?  And what breaks out of the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not notice that... thank you for help :) the while loop should be stopped as soon as a non-used p_login is found.

Comment: Since the only statement within the `while` doesn't change `@p_login`, it may loop longer than intended.  Or perhaps you have made some changes not reflected in the question.  An edit would be in order.

Comment: Yes, I know. There is one more mistake,    set @p_login = substring(@p_lname,1, 3) + @suffix; should be in the while cycle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for calling a function is in fact incorrect:

Replace:

```
while (LoginExists @p_login = 'true')
```

with:

```
while (dbo.LoginExists (@p_login)= 'true')
```

Comment: That was already proposed in a comment by @HABO , I got the error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it. Well your problem now is line "INSERT INTO". Columns of table Student do not match what you are trying to insert. Put Student column names in brackets in front of VALUES keyword.

Comment: Oh, yes, sure... I did not notice that... so thank you, answer accepted :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
if exists(select * from Student where student.slogin = @p_login)
```

by

```
 if exists(select * from Student where Student.slogin = @p_login)
```

Upper 'S' in `student.slogin`   and i hope it work

Comment: I don't think T SQL is case-sensitive... + I have tried it and it doesn't work.